# How do I show the ranking images at winning post?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I am working on a racing game in Unity3d and I have to show the rank as the winners touch the winning point.

As the winners reach at the winning point the image of the winner number should pop up for 1-2 seconds that is it.

How do I do it? Can anyone sort out this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a script like the following, on your game object that will be used to display this text.

I don't know anything about your design, so take this as a starting point.

```
float Timer = 2;
bool Active;

void Start()
{
    SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    SpriteRenderer.enabled = false;
}

public void SetActive()
{
    Active = true;
    Timer = 2;
    SpriteRenderer.enabled = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Active)
    {
        Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (Timer <= 0)
        {
             SpriteRenderer.enabled = true;
             Active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer I will let you know after doing it as I wanted and if you down voted to my question then please let me where I am wrong to ask the question. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, I suspect it is because you didn't demonstrate what you have tried, or provided any code samples of your attempts.

Comment: But I have never used "SpriteRenderer " so I am not aware of it and don't know how to use it so I will have to take some time for study this and then will implement. And I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I used SpriteRenderer under the assumption that your message would be displayed as a image.  You could just as well use a TextMesh.  If you are writing in 3D, then a SpriteRenderer is more than likely not what you want to use.

Comment: http://www.kironinteractive.com/demo/dashingderby/ Refer this and in the last have a look how the ranking process works well. That I want

Comment: That doesn't really help me... I think you should probably try to explain your question better, and repost?  It is very difficult to try to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you seen that I gave you ??

Comment: In the end at the winning post 1st three horses win so they slow down for a while that I did by Time.timeScale but after that the image also pop up with the winning horse's number that shows the respective horse number won so I want that ranking which pop up at the winning time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30540/discussion-between-shraddha-patel-and-jon).

Comment: Have you found something regarding my problem?

Comment: Have you found something regarding my problem?

Comment: No,  I am currently in the chat room you opened above, if you want to come discuss it